# synchronizing music files in openframeworks

Tags: openframeworks

If I want to split a song I wrote into several separate .wav files, such as "drums.wav" "bass.wav" "guitar.wav" etc...  is there anyway to have openFrameworks play all three files EXACTLY in sync so that the impression of a whole song is still there?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use ofSoundPlayer? If that is not good enough ofSoundStream should provide you with enough hooks to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question and all you want to do is play the files at the same time then you just have to create an ofSoundPlayer for each sample and set them to play at the same time.

In ofApp.h:

```
ofSoundPlayer drums, guitar, bass; // create sample players
```

In ofApp.cpp:

```
void ofApp::setup(){

drums.loadSound("drums.wav"); // do the same for bass and guitar

drums.play(); // play sample from start, same for bass and guitar


}

void ofApp::update(){

ofSoundUpdate();

}
```

This is assuming that all the samples start in sync. If you want to start a sample from a different position you can use:

```
drums.setPosition(float percent)
```

This is all well documented at http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/sound/ofSoundPlayer.html and is in the OpenFrameworks soundPlayer example (examples/sound/soundPlayerExample).

If you like things a little more complicated, I recommend Maximilian. It offers a lot of control, has a sample player and has an OpenFrameworks implementation but has less in the way of documentation. https://github.com/micknoise/Maximilian

Comment: That sounds great, but my tracks still have a bit of "drift" even when I start them at the same time.  I can take a look at the raw tracks, but I'm pretty sure they are all starting at exactly the beginning of the file.  Anyways, thanks for the pointer to Maximillian, that sounds great.  I tried to get CSOUND working with openFrameworks for a while but gave up... it would be nice to have something similar.